# Is SecKeychainAddGenericPassword vulnerable to hack

Tags: ios

Recently this hack has been documented: 
[Lost iPhone? Lost Passwords!](http://www.sit.fraunhofer.de/en/Images/sc_iPhone%20Passwords_tcm502-80443.pdf)

The paper says:

“The technique doesn't retrieve passwords stored in parts of the device that remain off limits until the passcode is entered. But this does not include virtual private networks, Wi-Fi networks, LDAP accounts, voicemail systems and Microsoft Exchange accounts”

I am using SecKeychainAddGenericPassword to store passwords in the keychain. The docs on the API say: "This function sets the initial access rights for the new keychain item so that the application creating the item is given trusted access." but the docs also say: "The iOS gives an application access to only its own keychain items. The keychain access controls discussed in this section do not apply to iOS." in the section where trusted applications are defined.

This post (http://blog.agile.ws/lost-iphone-safe-passwords/) talks about "iOS Protection classes" but I can't find anywhere that details what protection classes SecKeychainAddGenericPassword uses.

Does anyone know is SecKeychainAddGenericPassword is vulnerable to the documented hack?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that attack is on the system-wide key chain that SecKeychainAddGenericPassword uses.  But, if memory serves, it only works on jailbroken devices, so for normal users, an attacker will need physical access to the phone in order to jailbreak it first.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing with the keychain_dumper tools from [here](https://github.com/ptoomey3/Keychain-Dumper) It does require a device to be jail broken but passwords stored with SecKeychainAddGenericPassword are not accessible without the device being unlocked, so they are not vulnerable to the documented hack.